# What has happened to defbefore in Pedestal interceptors?

Tags: clojure, pedestal

I am following this blog post on Pedestal (http://www.rkn.io/2014/08/01/async-interceptors/) which makes reference to io.pedestal.interceptor -> defbefore. Using the latest Pedestal this function/macro is not present. What has become of it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They've just been moved to `io.pedestal.interceptor.helpers` namespace [in this commit](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/commit/c6e4a1f7e9c411cc83305ddcc451a954ab931ddc).